# Render attribute to the JS calendar JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, calendar

This is `JS` function, which initialize calendar:

```
function InitCalendar() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: {
            url: '/vacation/SchedulesGet',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                title: 'title',                      
                id : 'id',
                start: new Date('start'),
                end: new Date('end'),
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
            },
            color: 'yellow',
            textColor: 'black'
        },
        viewRender: function () {
            $('.fc-content').attr('data-id', id);
```

And this is `Action`:

```
public virtual JsonResult SchedulesGet()
        {
            var vacationRequests = new List<dynamic>();

            foreach (var item in _service.GetVacationRequestsWithProfiles().ToArray())
            {
                int vacationLength = ((item.DateEnd - item.DateStart).Days + 1);
                string day;
                if (vacationLength > 1)
                    day = " days";
                else
                    day = " day";
                vacationRequests.Add(new
                {
                    start = item.DateStart,
                    end = item.DateEnd,
                    title = item.Profile.FirstName
                            + " " + item.Profile.LastName
                            + " (" + item.VacationType.Type
                            + ") " + vacationLength + day,                    
                    //url = "/VacationRequest/Edit/" + item.Id
                    id = item.Id
                });
            }

            return Json(vacationRequests, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I need to set to `div` blocks `data-id` attributes. All others functions in `viewRender: function` works fine. But with this line  `$('.fc-content').attr('data-id', id);` calendar doesn't work. May anyone help me?

Comment: where do you define `id`?

Comment: Check pls public virtual JsonResult SchedulesGet()

Comment: You are not providing enough information, so it's hard to help you. In `SchedulesGet` you create JSON, but the question is where `id` in `viewRender` is comes from?

Comment: I think  dfsq makes a good point about id and it seems the mostly likely point of failure.  Suggest inspecting the value with the script debugger to ensure that it is defined.  You might also try hard coding an id to see if that makes it work.